What regex pattern can I use to work with ISBNs?
I require a pattern that will search for the correct ISBNs in the file.
Only the pattern itself needs to be implemented using regular expressions
My code so far:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Libary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void LibrarySearcher(string file_books)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(file_books))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
            }

            string books = File.ReadAllText(file_books);

            string pattern = @"\b(?:ISBN(?:-1[03])?:?\s*)?[-0-9]{1,5}[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9X]\b";

            
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(books, pattern);

            
            Console.WriteLine("Founded ISBN-s:");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                LibrarySearcher("dataBASE.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

string pattern = @"\b(?:ISBN(?:-1[03])?:?\s*)?[-0-9]{1,5}[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9X]\b";
Input:
ISBN 978-5-317-04434-3
ISBN 978-5-93286-181-3
ISBN 5-272-00341-1
ISBN 5-272-00251-1

ISBN 5-272---00251--1

ISBN 0-12-345678-9

Output:
ISBN 978-5-317-04434-3

ISBN 978-5-93286-181-3

ISBN 5-272-00341-1

ISBN 5-272-00251-1

272---00251

ISBN 0-12-345678-9

It is expected that it will be withdrawn
ISBN 978-5-317-04434-3

ISBN 978-5-93286-181-3

ISBN 5-272-00341-1

ISBN 5-272-00251-1


Is there anything c# specific about it or why the tag? Have you tried putting that regex and test data into regex101.com and see what it tells you?

Please [edit] the question and add the code in which you use the regular expression.

dataBASE.txt  contains: ISBN 978-5-317-04434-3
ISBN 978-5-93286-181-3
ISBN 5-272-00341-1
ISBN 5-272-00251-1
ISBN 1-1-1-1
ISBN 5-272---00251--1
ISBN 0-12-345678-9

with the pattern ^(?:ISBN(?:-1[03])?:?\ s*)?[-0-9]{1,5}[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0- 9X]$ regex101.com outputs what I need, but when I try to output in my code using this pattern, in response, he writes that matches = null

A valid ISBN is more than just a pattern. The digits can be run thru a calculation to check for typos/invalid series

Did you try it like this? (?m)^ISBN(?:-1[03])?:? ?[-0-9]{1,5}[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9]+[- ]?[0-9X]$ https://regex101.com/r/46VNQ8/1
